# Is this the Clean Data pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns

What is the name of the pattern in which every piece of data that the presentation layer gets and saves is as simple as possible with no ef context info attached?

eg.

```
CustomerManager manager = new CustomerManager();
Customer customer = manager.GetCustomerByEmail(string emailAddress);
DoSomething(customer);
manager.Save(customer);
```

And is this recommended for use in MVC? I see so many examples where controllers and view models are using ef contexts. It strikes me as bad practice.

PS. My reference to the "Clean Data" pattern was just my best guess and not a reference to an actual pattern.

Comment: This looks more domain-driven to me.. not sure I've ever come across the "Clean Data" pattern. What you're probably thinking ahout is "Active Record".

Answer (score 2):

I've never come across the "Clean Data" pattern.. but this looks more like the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern).

Generally when applying this pattern, your domain objects have `Insert()`, `Update()` and `Delete()` methods on them.

Its not often you see this approach these days. People tend to prefer keeping the persistence logic and business logic decoupled.. whereas this approach leads you down the path of them being very intertwined. This makes it harder to test and the codebase becomes resistant to changes.

Comment: I would have my CRUD methods in the Manager classes and not in the object classes. The object classes would be as simple as possible with the Manager classes containing all of the business logic. I would also want separation between business logic and persistence logic but what I'm focusing on here is the separation between presentation and business layers.

Answer (score 1):

The named pattern that I tend to use is the "repository" pattern, where the repository encapsulates the implementation details of how the data access layer is used. That way you can switch from EF (or whatever) without your controller-layer code needing to know about it.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Comment: I've had a look at the link. It seems too complex for what I'm trying to achieve. Do you know of a simpler similar pattern?

Comment: The implementation of a repository is only as complex as it needs to be. My repository classes expose only the specific methods that I need in the types that consume them.